# Raspberry Pi Zero - 5 or 5.1 volts?

Tags: power-supply, pi-zero

I am doing a little project where I power Raspberry Pi Zero from motorcycle battery (even when the bike is running). I have a step down converter which is set to 5V between the battery and Pi. But I don't know which voltage to use, 5 or 5.1 volts? The output from converter is connected to GPIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 5V and 5.1V should be fine.

I would go with 5.1V as that is the voltage of the official Pi micro usb power supply.

Answer (score 1):

The Pi power supplies output 5.1V - this is to compensate for the voltage drop in the cable.

The current consumption of the Pi Zero is so low this is unlikely to be a problem.

Provided you don't exceed 5.25V there should be no issue but be aware that many cheap step down converters have poor regulation so I would use 5V, but you should check what your converter ACTUALLY outputs on no load>